# Pandas grouped aggregation using two (or more values)

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder if there is a pretty way to do the following

I have a pandas df with the columns `country, user_id, actual_value, prediction`

I would like to calculate the accuracy per country. The accuracy method expects two arrays. One for the actuals and one for the pred

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ('DEU', 'a', 1, 1),
        ('DEU', 'b', 1, 0),
        ('GBR', 'c', 0, 0),
        ('GBR', 'c', 0, 1),
    ],
    columns=['country', 'user_id', 'actual_value', 'prediction']
)
```

I know that I can iteratively select the slices of the df that I want and calculate the metric. I wonder if I could somehow feed the two values (`actuals`, `prediction`) into an aggregation function.

I guess, going a bit against pandas conventions, I could create a column that contains both values in a tuple. Something like,

```py
df['actuals_predictions'] = df[['actual_value', 'prediction']].apply(lambda row: tuple(row), axis=1)
```

and then create a wrapper to my accuracy function that would first extract the arrays from the tuples and call the metric

```py
def acc_wrapper(actuals_predictions):
    actuals = [a for a, _ in actuals_predictions]
    predictions = [p for _, p in actuals_predictions]

    return balanced_accuracy_score(actuals, predictions)
```

and then do something like

```py
df.groupby('country').actuals_predictions.agg(acc_wrapper)

country
DEU    0.5
GBR    0.5
Name: e, dtype: float64
```

But I wonder if there is a more classy way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may just pass `balanced_accuracy_score` this function to `apply`

```
df['actuals_predictions'] = df.groupby('country').apply(lambda row: balanced_accuracy_score(row['actual_value'], row['prediction']), axis=1)
```

Comment: It's so weird, I've never used the apply after groupby's